# Accessing child component's method when nested within another component

Tags: javascript, angular

I'd like to be able to access the `SearchResults` component, (when it has been clicked), in the root component (AppComponent) as I'm looking to set different properties on the `SearchResults` component such as;

- I'd like to set an attribute on the `SearchResults` component so that it shows the "close" text
- Also, I'd to set the click event on the `SearchResults` to redirect elsewhere or actually enable it as a multi-select so that it stays selected until a user proceeds to the next step for example.

I'm trying to make the `SearchResults` and `SearchResult` components as re-usable as possible so we're able to state in the parent component which would include the `<app-searchresults>` selector what action we'd like our `SearchResults` components to actually be when they are clicked.

The only way I can really see doing this is using `EventEmitter` to pass the event up once through the `SearchResult` component then onto the parent component and then a Service to hold selected values but I'm still stuck around enabling the `SearchResults` component as either a component which redirects when clicked or stays selected? Is this actually possible or do I need to create a different `SearchResults` component for each different state I'd like?!

```
export class AppComponent  {

  @ViewChildren(SearchresultComponent) components: QueryList<SearchresultComponent>;

  name = 'Angular';

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.components.changes.subscribe((r) => { console.log(r) });
  }
}
```

**SearchResults.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-searchresults',
  templateUrl: './searchresults.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./searchresults.component.css']
})
export class SearchresultsComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChildren(SearchresultComponent) components: QueryList<SearchresultComponent>;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**SearchResults.html**

```
<h1>Search Results<h1>

<app-searchresult result ="first"></app-searchresult>
<app-searchresult result ="second"></app-searchresult>
<app-searchresult result ="third"></app-searchresult>
```

**SearchResult.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-searchresult',
  templateUrl: './searchresult.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./searchresult.component.css']
})
export class SearchresultComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  result: string;

  isSelected: boolean;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  toggleClickedState(){
    if(!this.isSelected){
      this.isSelected = !this.isSelected;
    }
  }
}
```

**SearchResult.html**

```
<div>
  <p (click)=toggleClickedState() [ngClass]="isSelected? 'selected' : '' "> Search Result : {{result}}</p>
  <p *ngIf="isSelected" class="cross" (click)="isSelected = false;">close</p>
<div>
```

I've included a link to structure of an app that references the above;
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjhovx

Comment: If you would, please post all the code relevant to the question *in the question itself* - don't hide it behind a link. You shouldn't tell potential helpers who would otherwise love to help that they have to navigate offsite just to have an idea of what you're working with. If the link breaks, the question could be rendered useless to future readers. Please edit your code into the question in a [MCVE], or the question might get closed, thanks.